# Swift 1.2: Obnoxious snippet shows Types can be shadowed by variable identifiers

Tags: swift, syntax, types, scope

Why is this allowed in Swift:

```
// Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.4, OS X 10.10.4
// Running within an iOS App, not a Playground
func wtf() {
    var String = 3
    var Int = "3a"
    println(String) // outputs 3
    println(Int)    // outputs 3a
    println(Int.toInt()) // outputs nil; clearly acting as a String
    // var x: String = "abc" // Not OK: 'String' is not a type
}
```

Types and variable bindings can intefere with each other? Even the fundamental types?

Answer (score 0):

In a "real" environment (not Playground) I get an error message in the 1st line --> *Use of local variable 'Int' before its declaration*

If I comment out the 1st line, the code compiles and after adding lines to print `x` and `y` I get

```
Swift.String
3
Optional(3)
abc
abc
```

Comment: But this doesn't explain anything. Updated to be within a real App. Errors are different but fundamental issue is the same.